# HTML5 Histroy API/History.js how to go to a shorter URL when coming from a long one

Tags: javascript, history.js, html5-history

I want to be able to do someting similar to Dropbox.
 when accessing the URL

> site.com/folder1/folder2/folder/folder4

through a regular request how can I use the history API so I can jump to folder1(I want to set the link to site.com/folder1) when I havent loaded all the links with the client? Reading through the specification I was left with the impression that this is impossible but Dropbox for example has such client side functionality.
**EDIT: Problem solved. See comments**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't understand. Do you want a navigation to jump to folders above the current in your directory tree? What have you tried so far? Did you write any code yet?

Comment: When I load the page site.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4 with a regular web page request, I want to set the URL to site.com/folder1 afterwards using history API without loading the full page site.com. I wrote some code but it doesnt work as I want it to. It just keeps appending the folder1 continously to the site.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4 and keeps getting longer and longer

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: History.replaceState(null, null, '/' + folderName); So Im using this(using History.js library) and it just appends folderName to site.com/folder1/folder2/folder3 instead of making it site.com/folderName

Comment: Cannot reproduce, [your code](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/20316097/) replaces the entire URI from the document root when I try it.

Comment: Your example acutally helped me to realize where was the problem. It appers that when you push something beginning with a slash, it rewrites the whole URL while if you push something without a slash it appends it to the current URL. This was harder to realize on a localhost where my root domain for my app contains several slash paths. Thank you for your help.